# How to validate many xml files by one XSD file

Tags: java, xml

How to validate many XML files by one XSD. There is one condition. They have different root element names. Im parsing XML using java. I know a little about XSD and DTD. Is it possible to use one XSD file for such XML files? How to this XSD file must look like (Im intrested in root name difinition)?

I found that I can validate XML files using XSD. My goal is to check many XML files. Their structure look like this `<root>someTextYouWant</root>` (simple example for question,the real structure is more difficult). In every file root name will be different(abc,sdfjsn,someStringYouWant). How to define XSD file that can admits that root element will have different names. I want to use 1 XSD file to validate all XML files with the structure discribed above.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the content/structure XML files, it's not clear what you're exactly trying to do.

Comment: I have added some additional sentences

Comment: Are you sure you need XSD? It sounds like you might just be trying validate that the document is valid XML, rather than that it conforms to a schema.

Comment: this was just a simple example for question,the real file structure is more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of using XSD is to validate the structure of some XML document(s).

For example, `<xs:element name="root">` in XSD can correspond to `<root>` in XML.

Similarly, `<xs:element name="first_child" type="xs:string" />` can correspond to `<first_child>xyz</first_child>`. Note that XSD also specifies the type of the enclosed data here. It could be something like "xs:int" as well.

If you're talking about the contents of any XML element, XSD obviously need not put any restriction and different XML files can have different contents / values. If you're talking about elements themselves, you can have optional elements by using something like `minOccurs` attribute.

Without looking at exact XMLs, it's difficult to point towards the correct approach.

Comment: `<root>someTextYouWant</root>` is a content of XML file. You can put instead of root any string you want that suits NCNAME.

Comment: XSD needs you to specify the element names literally. So you cannot have a regex to allow different names. Your XSD actually needs to specify those elements <root>, <foo>, <bar> etc. There's something like <xs:any> element which allows placing any element inside a container like sequence or choice, but I don't think you're looking for that.

Comment: Can `<xs:any>` describe root elements?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

you Can do that by implementing the desired xsd file link in your XML file that you want to compare it against like this:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="desired_schema_link">
```

you can do this in every XML file you want to validate using xsd

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this `schema.xsd`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:complexType name="c1">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="c1e1" minOccurs="0" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="rootType" mixed="true">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="e1" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="e2" type="c1" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>


    <xs:element name="sdfjsn" type="rootType" />
    <xs:element name="abc" type="rootType" />

</xs:schema>
```

This validates `abc.xml` with `abc` as root element

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<abc xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema.xsd">
    <e1 />
    <e2>
        <c1e1 />
    </e2>
    <e2>
        <c1e1 />
    </e2>
</abc>
```

and `sdfjsn.xml` with `sdfjsn` as root element

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sdfjsn xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema.xsd">
    <e2> </e2>
    <e1 />
</sdfjsn>
```